# Unable to start nginx when running OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I'm running OpenVPN on an Ubuntu server.

When I try to start nginx now, it throws error:

'sudo: unable to resolve host ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx'

I realize this is b/c the routing has changed but how can I get it to continue to start up even when on OpenVPN?

Comment: Er, that's strange. Exactly how are you trying to start nginx?

Comment: sudo service nginx start

Comment: Eh? Can you upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or later?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 now

Comment: Then why did you run `sudo service nginx start`? and not `sudo systemctl start nginx`?

Comment: I get the same message with either one

Comment: Can you run `sudo` anything? Maybe the problem is sudo.

Comment: If I turn off the VPN it runs fine

Comment: Can you please answer my question?

Comment: Well, can you elaborate then? sudo seems to work fine, but maybe I'm not understanding what you're asking me to do.

Comment: sudo systemctl start nginx works great if the VPN is off. If VPN is on, I get 'sudo: unable to resolve host ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx'

Comment: I asked you if you can run anything else with `sudo` while the VPN is on.

Comment: Ah. You're right, I get the same message with any sudo command.

Comment: Thanks for helping narrow that down. Where might the issue be then?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/59517/75668

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But why would it only occur when running a VPN?

Comment: Because your VPN client is changing the local resolver configuration?